# Run script inside Docker container using Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, docker, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

[Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/overview-what-is-azure-machine-learning) provides provides encapsulation of the [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-environments) for your code to run. As far as I know you can specify custom Docker images and Dockerfiles to create an environment.

But in my specific use case, I want to run the script inside a specific Docker container. Does Azure ML provide some ways to run a script inside a custom Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported at the moment unless you do wget to get the script to execute. Docker context support will be added soon and should unblock the scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the info @vizhur
Do you have a link for the feature request or ticket to add Docker context support so that I can follow up?